# In peoplesoft User registration service SCC_USERREG, create account service operation "SCC_USERREG_CREATEACCT.v1" isnt working. Gives error.

Tags: web-services, soap, integration, peoplesoft

In peoplesoft User registration service `SCC_USERREG`,  create account service operation `SCC_USERREG_CREATEACCT.v1` isnt working.
Error I get:
 `An Error occurred processing this request (14098,286)`
I have checked `security settings, scc_guest, SCC_ss_template`

Answer (score 1):

How are you making the tests? With SOAP UI?
Is your gateway running and the handler active?

This service of mine works fine, but there were a trick with the XML (If I recall correct, it is with the constituent collection), so if you can post the XML here, it would be nice. BTW, which CS bundle are you?